# getting text from within the co-ordinates specified in qtp

Tags: qtp

Is there a function in qtp in which the co-ordinates to be considered can be specified and the text be extracted from with in the co-ordinates. for example i want the text only from a particular part in an image, so is there a function where in I can give the co-ordinates and the text is extracted from the image only within the co-ordinates.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use a `Text Area Output Value`? This uses QTP to use OCR (among other things) to get text from a selected screen area.